# Is this claim about Minimax proof correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, game-theory

## Context

I am reading about Convex Analysis and more specifically the famous [Minimax Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem). It goes on about what to do if the function is convex, strictly convex, concave and strictly concave. All of these I understand. However one piece of this is missing.

In the last paragraph, it says:

> Finally, the claim for the last equality in the formulation of theorem can be gotten from the following equality and taking note that $\inf \to \min$ and $\sup \to \max $.

The "equality" in question is (I am citing the full theorem)

> If
> \begin{align}
> (x_0, y_0) \in X \times B \text{ such that } K(x, y_0) \leq K(x_0, y_0) \leq K(x_0, y) 
> \end{align}
> then $(x_0, y_0)$ saddle point and then we can write
> \begin{align}
> \sup_{x \in A} \inf_{y \in B} K(x,y) = \inf_{y \in B} \sup_{x \in A} K(x,y)
> \end{align}

So basically what the author says is that by taking the aforementioned equality and putting $\min$ where $\inf$ and $\max$ where $\sup$ we can get the Minimax Theorem. My question is? How exactly? A function satisfying the inequality means that $(x_0, y_0)$ is saddle point. How can that translate to the equality?

I am not even sure if I put my thoughts correctly, since my learning book is quite poor in overall quality.

I am expecting for us to work through it.

Comment: How is this functional analysis or game theory?

Comment: Minimax theorem is the first theorem of game theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $K(x,y_0) \le K(x_0, y_0) \le K(x_0, y)$

It is always true that $\sup_x \inf_y K(x,y) \le \inf_y \sup_x K(x,y)$.

From the above we have $K(x,y_0) \le K(x_0, y_0) \le \inf_y K(x_0, y)$

$\sup_x K(x,y_0) \le K(x_0, y_0) \le \inf_y K(x_0, y)$

$\sup_x K(x,y_0) \le K(x_0, y_0) \le \inf_y K(x_0, y) \le \sup_x \inf_y K(x, y)$

$\inf_y \sup_x K(x,y) \le \sup_x K(x,y_0) \le K(x_0, y_0) \le \inf_y K(x_0, y) \le \sup_x \inf_y K(x, y)$

Comment: Wow, that's tough. Excuse me If I sound like a simpleton (I really did not understand even what this part of the proof is about) but where is the minimax equality in all this?

Comment: Your question asked how equality followed from the existence of a saddle. The above shows the relevant inequality required to show equality.